# PHP Mime type checking alternative way of doing it?

Tags: php

I noticed that get_mime() is now depreciated so what would be an alternative way of creating the following function? This function is used through a cms that I work with so need a reliable alternative.

```
// Mime Type Checker
function get_mime ($filename,$mode=0) {

    // mode 0 = full check
    // mode 1 = extension check only

    $mime_types = array(

        'txt' => 'text/plain',
        'htm' => 'text/html',
        'html' => 'text/html',
        'php' => 'text/html',
        'css' => 'text/css',
        'js' => 'application/javascript',
        'json' => 'application/json',
        'xml' => 'application/xml',
        'swf' => 'application/x-shockwave-flash',
        'flv' => 'video/x-flv',

        // images
        'png' => 'image/png',
        'jpe' => 'image/jpeg',
        'jpeg' => 'image/jpeg',
        'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
        'gif' => 'image/gif',
        'bmp' => 'image/bmp',
        'ico' => 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon',
        'tiff' => 'image/tiff',
        'tif' => 'image/tiff',
        'svg' => 'image/svg+xml',
        'svgz' => 'image/svg+xml',

        // archives
        'zip' => 'application/zip',
        'rar' => 'application/x-rar-compressed',
        'exe' => 'application/x-msdownload',
        'msi' => 'application/x-msdownload',
        'cab' => 'application/vnd.ms-cab-compressed',

        // audio/video
        'mp3' => 'audio/mpeg',
        'qt' => 'video/quicktime',
        'mov' => 'video/quicktime',

        // adobe
        'pdf' => 'application/pdf',
        'psd' => 'image/vnd.adobe.photoshop',
        'ai' => 'application/postscript',
        'eps' => 'application/postscript',
        'ps' => 'application/postscript',

        // ms office
        'doc' => 'application/msword',
        'rtf' => 'application/rtf',
        'xls' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
        'ppt' => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
        'docx' => 'application/msword',
        'xlsx' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
        'pptx' => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',


        // open office
        'odt' => 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text',
        'ods' => 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet',
    );

    $ext = strtolower(array_pop(explode('.',$filename)));

    if (function_exists('mime_content_type') && $mode==0) {
        $mimetype = mime_content_type($filename);
        return $mimetype;
    }

    if (function_exists('finfo_open') && $mode==0) {
        $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);
        $mimetype = finfo_file($finfo, $filename);
        finfo_close($finfo);
        return $mimetype;

    } elseif (array_key_exists($ext, $mime_types)) {
        return $mime_types[$ext];
    } else {
        return 'application/octet-stream';
    }
}
```

Comment: try using file info functions. may be you can get your results using http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php

Comment: FYI: [Generating MIME Type in PHP is not Magic](https://chrisjean.com/2009/02/14/generating-mime-type-in-php-is-not-magic/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[finfo_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) is the replacement for `mime_content_type`.

Since `finfo_file` is only avaliable in PHP 5.3.0+, what you have done is correct. If `finfo_file` is avaliable, then use it, otherwise fall back to mime_content_type, which should be avaliable if we can't use `finfo_file`.

You should update your conditional checking like this:

```
if(function_exists('mime_content_type')&&$mode==0){ 
        $mimetype = mime_content_type($filename); 
        return $mimetype; 

}elseif(function_exists('finfo_open')&&$mode==0){ 
        $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME); 
        $mimetype = finfo_file($finfo, $filename); 
        finfo_close($finfo); 
        return $mimetype; 
}elseif(array_key_exists($ext, $mime_types)){ 
        return $mime_types[$ext]; 
}else { 
        return 'application/octet-stream'; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used something like this a while ago, it seems to work okay as long as you have PHP version > 5.3.0:

```
$fn = "/dir/filename.whatever"
$mime = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME,$mimepath);
$filetype = finfo_file($mime,$fn);
finfo_close($mime);
```

Note; I remember that `$mimepath` is a variable that isn't set. That will result in `finfo_open()` using a default value for its second parameter.

Comment: Note that this could return a string such as "video/x-flv; charset=binary" and you may not want the "charset=binary" part. I'd suggest adding this line to the end of the above code if you want to return only the mime type: $mimetype = substr($mimetype, 0, strpos($mimetype, ';'));

Answer (score 0):

```
$mime = `file --mime-type $path`;
$mime = trim(array_pop(explode(':', $mime)));
```

This works for me.

Comment: `file -b --mime-type $path` works without the need for `trim(array_pop(explode(':', $mime)));`

Comment: Sorry to necro-comment, but there are real security concerns to be aware of with this approach.  The ticks execute a shell command so you need to *heavily* sanitize `$path', if you want to do mime checking this way. Also, you are using a POSIX command that has no guarantee of being on the system (i.e. Windows, customized Linux distro, other OS).