# Empty $_FILES PHP

Tags: php, html, image

So, I have a form to post a text to a blog. One of the informations include an image.

```
<label class="w3-text-black">Image:</label>
<input name="image" type="file"/>
<br></br>
<button name="submit" type="submit" class="w3-btn w3-gray w3-hover-black">Send</button>
```

And I have the PHP part that receives all that information, but only sends the rest to the DB and uploads the image to my server if the image is a PNG.

```
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES['image']['name']);

    if (strstr('.png', end($temp))){ //condition }
```

This code worked when used in my localhost, but once i uploaded it to my server, this error appeared: Warning: strstr(): Empty needle

And what $temp does is separate the extension with the use of explosion.

After that, i change the name of my file, so i can access it later with js.

```
$sqlImg = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = (SELECT MAX(post_id) FROM posts)";
            $resid = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlImg);
            $linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resid);
            $id = $linha['post_id'];

            $path = 'blogimg/blog_img' . $id . '.' . end($temp);

            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'], $path)){}
```

Comment: And if you don't have extension? Or `$_FILES['image']['name']` is empty?

Comment: I mean your filename will be `my_picture`.

Comment: I don't get it. What do you mean by that? That even though i select the file to upload, but yet i have nothing?

Comment: at least check if there is sth in $_FILES before you do use it. always validate input.

Comment: We don't do "SOLVED" in question titles here. If you solved your problem you can post the answer below and accept it.

Comment: Oh, thanks man. Didn't know about that, my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I The prolem was actualy pretty simple. I had the enctype set on my local file, but the file hosted in my server did not have it. So i added it and everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

You should not check the file extension with filename
instead of doing that.

```
$allowed =  array('png'); // n number of file types here
$filename = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(in_array($ext,$allowed) ) {
    // Do operations;
}
```

Comment: better use sth. like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35299457/getting-mime-type-from-file-name-in-php

Comment: I'm gonna edit the main question, so this code gts organized