# How to abort XMLHttpRequest.upload from the external script?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

## As a follow up to [Why is $_FILES[] always empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61093111/11743318):

When uploading a file via AJAX with PhP, one generally does the following (I’m new to this so please tell me if there is a better way to do this):

- Have one file with a form and javascript where you setup and send your `XMLHttpRequest`, e.g. **upload_form.php**
- Have another, external php file to process the upload request, e.g. **upload.php**

### **My question is this:**

Is it possible to abort the XMLHttpRequest from **within the external upload.php file?**.

*The reason for wanting to do this is that if the file already exists on the server, I'd like to abort the `XMLHttpRequest` rather than making the user wait until the upload has completed to be informed of the failure.*

---

### **Some images to illustrate the problem:**

I throttled the speed in the network tab in order to exaggerate the problem.

*The user uploads a file that **DOES NOT** exist on the server in the **uploads** directory:*

[image: Success]

*The user uploads a file that **DOES** exist on the server in the **uploads** directory:*

[image: Failure]

### **Some code to illustrate the problem:**

**upload_form.php:**

```html
<!-- enctype and method added on suggestions from previous question -->
<form class="form" id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="file_to_upload" id="file_to_upload"><br>
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>

<script>
  const upload_form  = document.getElementById('upload_form');
  var file_to_upload = document.getElementById('file_to_upload');

  upload_form.addEventListener("submit", upload_file);

  function upload_file (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

    xhr.open("POST", "upload.php");
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", e => {
      const percent = e.lengthComputable ? (e.loaded / e.total) * 100 : 0;
      console.log(percent.toFixed(0) + "%");
    });

    // ================= MAIN PART OF QUESTION ===================
    // Can I force this to fire from upload.php if file exists?
    xhr.addEventListener("abort", e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
    // ===========================================================

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        // update some response area here
      }
    };

    xhr.send(new FormData(upload_form));
  }
</script>
```

**upload.php:**

```php
<?php

$target_path = "uploads/".basename($_FILES["file_to_upload"]["name"]);
$uploaded_file = $_FILES['file_to_upload']['tmp_name'];

$upload_ok = true;
$errors = [];

// ================= MAIN PART OF QUESTION ==========================
// I want this to cause the abort event to fire on the XMLHttpRequest
if (file_exists($target_path)) {
  $upload_ok = false;
  array_push($errors, 'The file already exists on the server. Please rename the file and try again.');
}
// ==================================================================

if(!$upload_ok) {
  echo 'The file was not uploaded because:<br>';
  foreach ($errors as $err) {
    echo $err.'<br>';
  }
} else {
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file_to_upload"]["tmp_name"], $target_path)) {
    echo 'File uploaded successfully';
  } else {
    echo 'Something went wrong. Please try again.';
  }
}
?>
```

I've tried checking different combinations of `readyState` and `status` in **upload_form.php** but this hasn't helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time the PHP code is get to begin, the file has been fully uploaded so there is no point aborting it that way, which would be to simply return the message. Instead, you can make a prior to upload AJAX call and check if the file exists and only if it doesn't then upload the file or else message the user about it.

#### Create a simple `exists.php` with the following code

```php
<?php

$target_path = "uploads/".$_GET['file'];
$file_exists = file_exists($target_path);

header('Content-Type: application/json');

// Return a JSON object with a single boolean property to indicate if the file exists
echo json_encode(['exists' => $file_exists]);
```

#### Create a promise to make a XHR call and get the `exists.php` result

```js
function check_file_exists() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("GET", `exists.php?file=${encodeURIComponent(file_to_upload.files[0].name)}`);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        resolve(this.response && this.response.exists);
      }
    };

    xhr.send();
  });
}
```

#### Refactor the `upload_file` submit function to first call the `check_file_exists` promise

```js
// An element to display a message to the user
const message = document.getElementById('message');

function upload_file(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  message.textContent = '';

  // Call the promise to check if the selected file exists on the server
  check_file_exists().then(exists => {
    if(exists) {
      // If it exists message the user about it and do nothing else
      message.textContent = `File "${file_to_upload.files[0].name} already exists`;
    } else {
      // If it does not exists upload the file
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xhr.open("POST", "upload.php");
      xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", e => {
        const percent = e.lengthComputable ? (e.loaded / e.total) * 100 : 0;
        console.log(percent.toFixed(0) + "%");
      });

      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          // update some response area here
          message.textContent = this.responseText;
        }
      };

      xhr.send(new FormData(upload_form));
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Very nice answer. I've only just started to learn about `Promise` objects in javascript so it's nice to see them used in a context directly relevant to my own problem. Can you comment on whether there's any security implications with having an `exists.php` script that uses `$_GET` on your server? - e.g., could somebody snoop around for files using it?

Comment: Promises are very powerful and you should invest time to learn how they work and when you can make use of them. These two PHP files, not only the `exists.php` but also the `upload.php` are totally unsecure and should never be used as they are; instead, you have to create an authentication system (*or use some ready made auth systrems*) that will handle login sessions and only allow users that they have logged in and have access to upload and check only for files and folders that should have access to.

Comment: `GET` requests are totally fine when there is a backend authentication system that will check for users and access. There is nothing special that makes `POST` requests more secure than `GET` requests; there always must be a middleware auth system to check and allow/deny these requests accordingly.