# Restrict renamed file in Upload field + contact from 7

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

When trying to check the MIME file type it's not working. it's taking all files to restricted error. if game.exe is renamed as game.docx and uploaded then it need to be blocked. here am attaching the code. kindly anyone checks and please help me to solve the issue.

```
function cf7_custom_file_validation ($result, $tag) {
    if ($tag->name === 'file-234') {
        $contentType = mime_content_type($_FILES[$tag->name]['tmp_name']);
        if ($contentType !== 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' || $contentType !== 'application/pdf' || $contentType !== 'application/msword') {
            $result->invalidate($tag, 'This file type is not supported');
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use && instead of ||

Now, for example,  a pdf is different of word so will enter the if.

Comment: i have tried with && also. but it's not working. normal pdf and renamed pdf also I can upload. any idea to solve the issue. thanks in advance

Comment: can you please try above code from your end

Comment: make a var_dump of $contentType to see what mime type finds.

Comment: am checking that. at the time i couldn't see any response. so might be the $contentType not getting any details. i mean it's not checking the upload file MIME type

Comment: try to use :  $contentType = mime_content_type($_FILES['file-234']['tmp_name']);

Comment: yes did, but no result showing in response.

Comment: can you try the code from your end. please..

Comment: i guess you dont get to the file then ...  make a var_dump of $_FILES... to see what you get

Comment: when am trying to check json result of $_FILES it's getting results. But when am checking with " mime_content_type($_FILES); " not getting response

Comment: have a look on this, it has a good explanation about how to find mime type in php: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59986082/php-how-to-properly-check-mime-type-of-a-file

Comment: i have checked that. but it's not helped me properly. can you please help me to find out the issue?

Comment: can you try the code from your end please

Comment: Sorry, but I currently work in java, so I do not have a php server to try the code.

Comment: if it is possible. please check. because am stuck on here