# PHP imagecopyresampled() function only working for JPG Images

Tags: php, wordpress, image, gd

I'm trying to make an API request with PHP, but I first have to scale an image that I get from a form to a 1024 by 1024 resolution.
This PHP script works perfectly with JPG files, but with PNG files the PHP returns a 500 error message. It only works with files that are actually JPG, not PNG files, for example, which I have renamed to .jpg files.

```
$fileInfo = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name']);
$fileExtension = strtolower($fileInfo['extension']);

                
                $allowedExtensions = array(
                    'jpg',
                    'jpeg',
                    'png',
                    'gif',
                    'wbmp',
                    'webp'
                );
                $allowedMimeTypes = array(
                    'image/jpeg',
                    'image/png',
                    'image/gif',
                    'image/wbmp',
                    'image/webp'
                );

                // Überprüfe die Dateierweiterung und den MIME-Typ
                if (!in_array($fileExtension, $allowedExtensions) || !in_array($_FILES['image']['type'], $allowedMimeTypes)) {
                    echo "Fehler: Nur JPEG, PNG, GIF, WBMP und WEBP Dateien sind erlaubt.)";
                    exit;
                }

                // Überprüfen der Dateigröße
                if ($_FILES['image']['size'] > 5 * 1024 * 1024) { 
                    echo "Fehler: Die Datei darf nicht größer als 5 MB sein.)";
                    exit; 
                    
                }
                
                
                $imageInfo = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
                $imageWidth = $imageInfo[0];
                $imageHeight = $imageInfo[1];
                $imagePixelCount = $imageWidth * $imageHeight;

                if ($imagePixelCount > 1048576) { // 1.048.576 Pixel
                    echo "Fehler: Das Bild darf nicht mehr als 1.048.576 Pixel haben.)";
                    exit; 
                }
                
                // Neuskalierung Anfang
                // Neuskalierung Anfang
                
                // Devc Mail
                $to = 'info@example.com';
                $subject = 'Check1';
                $message = 'C';
                $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
                wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
                
                
                switch ($_FILES['image']['type']) {
                    case 'image/jpeg':
                    case 'image/pjpeg': // Manchmal wird JPEG auch als pjpeg dargestellt
                        $sourceImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
                        break;
                    case 'image/png':
                        $sourceImage = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
                        // PNG-Transparenz beibehalten
                        imagealphablending($resizedImage, false);
                        imagesavealpha($resizedImage, true);
                        break;
                    case 'image/gif':
                        $sourceImage = imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
                        break;
                    case 'image/webp':
                        $sourceImage = imagecreatefromwebp($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
                        break;
                    case 'image/bmp':
                    case 'image/x-windows-bmp':
                        $sourceImage = imagecreatefrombmp($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
                        break;
                    // ... Weitere unterstützte Formate ...
                    default:
                        echo "Fehler: Unbekanntes Bildformat.";
                        exit;
                }

                // Zielbild mit der neuen Größe erstellen
                $newWidth = 1024;
                $newHeight = 1024;
                $resizedImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);

                // TODO Fehler funktioniert nur für jpg dateien
                // Bild skalieren
                imagecopyresampled($resizedImage, $sourceImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $imageWidth, $imageHeight);

                // Speichern des skalierten Bildes
                // $tempFilePath = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] . "_resized." . $fileExtension;
                $tempFilePath = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] . "_resized";
                switch ($fileExtension) {
                    case 'jpg':
                    case 'jpeg':
                        imagejpeg($resizedImage, $tempFilePath);
                        break;
                    case 'png':
                        imagepng($resizedImage, $tempFilePath);
                        break;
                    case 'gif':
                        imagegif($resizedImage, $tempFilePath);
                        break;
                    // ... Fügen Sie andere unterstützte Formate hinzu ...
                }

                // Bereinigung
                imagedestroy($sourceImage);
                imagedestroy($resizedImage);
```

**The PHP limits:**

upload_max_filesize=67108864
memory_limit=805306368

I tried to scale a PNG image using PHP but got a 500 error.

**The error:**

```
2024-03-11T17:59:44+00:00 CRITICAL Uncaught ValueError: Path cannot be empty in /.../kbe_engine/bildzubild_V.1.20.php:297 CONTEXT: {"error":{"type":1,"file":"\/homepages\/44\/d4297367306\/htdocs\/wordpress\/kbe_engine\/bildzubild_V.1.20.php","line":297},"backtrace":["","#0 \/homepages\/44\/d4297367306\/htdocs\/wordpress\/kbe_engine\/bildzubild_V.1.20.php(297): curl_setopt()","#1 {main}","thrown"]}
```

Comment: To debug this, I'd skip everything as it relates to APIs, WordPress or even `$_FILES`. Instead just hard-code a PNG file that you know is good at the top, and let your code work with that. Your error message makes it sounds like it isn't an image processing error.

Comment: Also, I don't know if I'd recommend trusting the client-provided MIME type, you might want to do this server-side: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59986578/231316

Comment: Which is line 297 of `bildzubild_V.1.20.php`?

Comment: The quoted error message appears to come from curl_setopt, presumably because you are passing an empty path for a file upload. But the actual error is likely to occur earlier, for example in the PNG case, in that first `switch`, you do `imagealphablending($resizedImage, false);` - but does `$resizedImage` even exist at this point? `$resizedImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);` comes _after_ that first switch, and before, I don't see that variable name used.