# Laravel stored svg file as html

Tags: php, laravel, svg, laravel-5

Helo everyone. I try to make simple media library and have strange issue during svg upload.
here are my controller method:

```
$file = $request->file('image');
            $data['name'] = $file->store('/media/original', 'public');
            $data['mime_type'] = $file->getMimeType();
            $data['file_size'] = $file->getSize();
            $data['file_status'] = 1;

            Gallery::create($data);
```

A problem is svg stores with .html extension. `$file->getMimeType();` returns `text/plain`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Mime type checking alternative way of doing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225644/php-mime-type-checking-alternative-way-of-doing-it)

Comment: please go through https://github.com/directus/directus/issues/1166 i think you may get some help regarding this issue